# Adding {fold} value to templateUrl in AngularJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hi im trying to capture the value of the {fold} and add it to the templateUrl. But the php file show.person.php returns an error because it only sees 'id' as '{fold}' and not as number like '54'

in my conifg.router.js file:

```
.state('show.person', {
url: '/person/{fold}',
views: {
'': {
templateUrl: 'tpl/show.person.php?id={fold}'
},
'footer': {
templateUrl: 'tpl/show.footer.php'
}
}
})
```

In another php file, the link to trigger the router state ...

```
<php $person = '54';?>

<a ui-sref="show.person({fold:'<?php echo $person?>'})">View</a>
```

Inside show.person.php

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

I get the result '{fold}' what I should be getting is '54'.

Thank you for any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Could i have the following error ?

You should use a function to do this inside the ui-sref to get your state name. It's not proper.

Morever, you need to use a double **{{}}** when you want to use a scope variable.

And i'm sure it's not the proper way to define your state.

Tell me more about your code and error and i will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks Llies, inside show.person.php i want to process the 'id' variable value using php $ _GET['id']. At the moment $ _GET['id'] is seeing it as the string {fold} and not as the number 54. if i do this to templateUrl: 'tpl/show.person.php?id=54' then it works fine. But i need it to work dynamically. Hope that makes sense.